# Change text bold with button in form input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble changing the input in a form bold by clicking on the B link. It works if I change `<input>` to a `<div>`, but it won't work as an `<input>`. I have posted my code below. I am struggling to solve this issue.

```js
$('.bold_text').toggle(function() {
  $('#notes').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}, function() {
  $('#notes').css('font-weight', 'auto');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="bold_text">B</button>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Write your notes here...">
  <input class="save_button" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: Note sure if this typo is just in your example or your actual code, but `$$('.bold_text')`

Comment: Jquery `toggle` actually toggles show/hide of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). You may want to create a class and toggle it using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead:

```js
$('.bold_text').click(function() {
  $('#notes').toggleClass('bold');
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="bold_text">B</button>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Write your notes here...">
  <input class="save_button" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```